# Variable working for if statement, but not click functions

Tags: jquery

I am new here and was looking to see if I could get something answered.

How come the variable works for the first if statement, but not the click functions?

```
var Page = $.cookie('Page')

$(function () {

    if (Page == '0') $('.mainmenu #active').addClass('disable');

    $('.pageback').click(function () {
        if (Page == '1') $('.mainmenu #active').addClass('disable');
    }); // disable menu navigation  

    $('.pagenext').click(function () {
        if (Page == '0') $('.mainmenu #active').removeClass('disable');
    }); // disable menu navigation
});
```

Comment: And you're claiming `Page` is undefined inside the click functions, but not outside them ?

Comment: Isn't that because you're not actually setting the variable after you're using it?

Comment: the variable seems to work for the initial if statement. But when clicking pageback and pagenext it will not run.

Comment: A quick fix to ensure that your Page variable is indeed correct would be to replace all mentions of Page and replace them with $.cookie('Page');

Comment: Run how? You never change the value of Page ?

Comment: I think he means the if statment is not executed. As in the Page Var is not correct, more that it always evaluates to false.

Comment: The cookie value is changed elsewhere in the code.

Comment: Just console.log the value of Page, and see what it is !

Answer (score 0):

The `Page` variable is assigned once from a cookie.

```
var Page = $.cookie('Page')
```

However, it is *never changed* so the value will remain the same until the cookie is changed *and* the page is refreshed. That is, the assignment to the `Page` variable occurs only when evaluated. It is equivalent to saying `var Page = 'x'` where x is the value of the cookie at the given point in time.

---

While this still won't update the class *when* the cookie is updated (the cookie needs to be set and *then* the click needs to occur), consider using a function which can be used to defer evaluation instead of a variable. Also note the other changes.

```
$(function () {

    function pageNo () {
       return parseInt($.cookie('Page'), 10) || 0;
    }

    var menu = $('.mainmenu #active');

    if (pageNo() == 0) menu.addClass('disable');

    $('.pageback').click(function () {
        if (pageNo() == 1) menu.addClass('disable');
    }); // disable menu navigation  

    $('.pagenext').click(function () {
        if (pageNo() == 0) menu.removeClass('disable');
    }); // disable menu navigation
});
```

To ensure the classes are changed *when* the cookie changes, jQuery events may be useful (does the cookie plugin support any by default?) to trigger an update. I use KnockoutJS and find it makes this sort of dependency management easy.